# Camera Preview code gives as upside down image view android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am Using a onCLick over a button to capture an image but when we see the preview it is upside down in vertical mode where as when the same preview is seen through horizontal preview renders correctly.
Please let me know what tweaks are necessary to readjust the preview.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into account, that camera preview image origin is on top right corner if in portait mode, and axes are swapped -  and it does not depend on phone orientation.  You will have to flip image to display it in portrait mode properly.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at

```
android.hardware.Camera.setDisplayOrientation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html
```

and

```
android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.setRotation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html
```